# Dealing with a generated column in a Quarkus Panache entity

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I have a column in a table that gets calculated from two other fields.
I added the field by the following flyway migration script:

```
alter table if exists myentity
    add weeklyhour integer not null generated always as ( "weekday" * 24 + "hour" ) STORED;
```

The corresponding Panache entity looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
public class MyEntity extends PanacheEntity {
    private int weekday;
    private int hour;
    // this is the generated column
    private int weeklyhours;
    // + getter and setters ...
```

If I now try to persist an entity I get the following exception:
`ERROR: cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column "weeklyhour" Detail: Column "weeklyhour" is a generated column.`

How can I tell hibernate that the field `weeklyhours` is computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Hibernate related problem and not specific to Panache.
You can annotated property with
`@Formula("weeklyhour")` or `@Column(name="weeklyhour", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Comment: I got it to work with a `@DynamicInsert` annotation at class level and `@Generated` and `@ColumnDefault(value = "0")` annotation on the property itself but your solution is cleaner. Thank you!